# Build an array of hashes from an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following:

```
array_of_hashes = [{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}, {"a" => 3, "b" => 4}]
```

I want to convert this to something like:

```
new_hash = [{"cow" => 1, "dog" => 2}, {"cow" => 3, "dog" => 4}]
```

I tried the following:

```
new_hash = {}
array_of_hashes.each do |a|
  new_hash["cow"] = a["a"]
  new_hash["dog"] = a["b"]
end
```

However, `new_hash` results in only the second hash from `array_of_hashes`:

```
new_hash = {"cow"=>3, "dog"=>4}
```

**For those that need an explicitly stated question:
How can I map `array_of_hashes` to get `new_hash` (as defined in my first 2 lines of code)?**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa, The question is *clearly implied* ... see the consistent responses below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are turning an array of hashes into a single hash. You're missing the whole **array** part.

You want

```
new_array = []
array_of_hashes.each do |a|
  new_hash = {}
  new_hash["cow"] = a["a"]
  new_hash["dog"] = a["b"]
  new_array << new_hash
end
```

If you were to write this more idiomatically, you'd produce something like this:

```
new_array = array_of_hashes.map do |hash|
  { "cow" => hash['a'], "dog" => hash['b'] }
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew I was doing something really wrong! Looks like you don't need that first new_hash in your loop, but otherwise works perfectly

Comment: @Abram You absolutely need `new_hash = {}` in the first loop, otherwise you're going to be continually appending the same hash to the array, and overwriting its values each iteration.

Comment: Oh hey, good point, now that you've added the `= {}` part that makes more sense!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps these will help you understand what you're doing wrong:

Your code is:

```
array_of_hashes = [{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}, {"a" => 3, "b" => 4}]

new_hash = {}
array_of_hashes.each do |a|
  new_hash # => {}, {"cow"=>1, "dog"=>2}
```

The first time through, `new_hash` is `{}`. The second time through it's `{"cow"=>1, "dog"=>2}`.

```
  new_hash["cow"] = a["a"] # => 1, 3
```

The first time through, you assign `1` to the value associated with the `cow` key and the second time you overwrite it with `3`.

```
  new_hash["dog"] = a["b"] # => 2, 4
```

This is similar to above. You're overwriting the values.

```
  new_hash # => {"cow"=>1, "dog"=>2}, {"cow"=>3, "dog"=>4}
end
```

Resulting in:

```
new_hash # => {"cow"=>3, "dog"=>4}
```

Instead, you *could* write:

```
new_array = []
```

You really want to accumulate into an array, not to a hash since hashes can't hold multiple instances of the same keys.

```
array_of_hashes.each do |h|
  new_array # => [], [{"cow"=>1, "dog"=>2}]
```

The first time through `new_array` is empty. The second time it has the previous loop's hash.

```
  new_array << {
    'cow' => h['a'],
    'dog' => h['b']
  }
```

Append a new hash to the array.

```
  new_array # => [{"cow"=>1, "dog"=>2}], [{"cow"=>1, "dog"=>2}, {"cow"=>3, "dog"=>4}]
```

You can see the array accumulating the sub-hashes.

```
end
new_array # => [{"cow"=>1, "dog"=>2}, {"cow"=>3, "dog"=>4}]
```

That said, I'd do it with a simple `map` as [@meager suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31839458/128421).

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same as @meagar's answer, but I included it to show how you might implement it in a fairly general way.

```
def replace_em(arr, replacements)
  arr.map do |h|
    h.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),g|
      g[replacements.key?(k) ? replacements[k] : k] = v
    end
  end
end

arr = [{ "a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3 }, { "a"=>3, "b"=>4, "d"=> 5 }]
replacements = { "a"=>"cow", "b"=>"dog", "e"=>"cat" }

replace_em(arr, replacements)
  #=> [{"cow"=>1, "dog"=>2, "c"=>3}, {"cow"=>3, "dog"=>4, "d"=>5}]
```

Comment: I like that you inject a mapping to solve the general problem.

Comment: If that's my regular downvoter, you have, as always, brought a smile to my face.